# Perticular Solr core fills up all hard disk space

Tags: solr

I have a SOLR instance running with a couple of cores, each one of them having between 15 to 25 million documents. Normally the size of each core index (on the disk) is around 30-50 GB each, but there is one particular core index that keeps increasing until hard disk space is full (raising up to 200 GB and more).

When I look at other indexes all files are from the current day, but this one core keeps files also from 4-5 days ago (I guess the data is always duplicated on every import).

What could be causing such behavior and what should I look for when debugging it? Thanks.

Comment: Which files are left behind? Can it be that a new searcher isn't opened? Have you tried calling optimize on the index? Is there a different mergeFactor configured for the index?

Comment: Are those cores configured the same way or differently? Perhaps you have auto-commit on the smaller cores and missing one on the larger core. Is the document count different? You need to drill down into the next level of differences beyond just overall size.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, I will do further investigation today and see if I can find any differences..